# Verificar campos vazios com foreach

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo um sistema de formulários aonde os campos são gerados pela data base através de select. O mesmo é feito com foreach, como posso buscar na data base os campos obrigatórios e ver se eles foram preenchidos? E caso não forem não validar o formulário e mostrar uma mensagem. 
**OBS: Não quero utilizar required no input.**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['acao'])) {
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)){ 
    mysql_query("insert into cms_formularios_respostas(usuario,resposta,campo,formulario) values('$name','".strip_tags($val)."','$key','$row[id]')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-bottom:5px"> 
<input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /> 
<?php
$get_form = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cms_formularios_campos WHERE formulario = '$row[id]' ORDER BY ID") or die(mysql_error());
while($form = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_form)){
?><p><label class="label-form" for="<?php echo $form['id']; ?>"><?php echo $form['nome']; ?></label><br /><?php if($form['tipo'] == 'Resposta curta'){ ?><inputtype="text" name="<?php echo $form['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $form['id']; ?>" class="input-form" /><br><?php if($form['obrigatorio'] == 'sim'){ ?><span style="color:red">* Requerido</span><?php } ?><?php } ?></p><input type="submit" class="input-form" value="Enviar" />
```

Comment: Pode ser feito somente com javascript pode ser?

Comment: Olá Felipe! Então eu não queria por javascript. Vi em um site o mesmo sistema e era feito por php mesmo, na hora de inserir na data base verificava os campos obrigatórios do formulário se foram preenchidos, caso contrário mostrava a mensagem Você deixou o campo [NOME DO CAMPO] em branco que era obrigatório.

Comment: Pois bem, então pode ser feito no servidor mas não será em tempo real, toda vez que o usuário submeter o formulário, irá para outra página de validação, ao voltar os dados preenchidos serão perdidos.

Comment: Mesmo assim, prefiro no servidor!

Comment: ok, já respondo.

Comment: E como deve ser feito para saber qual campo é obrigatório? Pela coluna `obrigatorio`? E mesmo que faça tal verificação no servidor, que deve ser feita, recomendo fortemente utilizar o `required` no HTML. Isso evitará que o usuário faça múltiplas requisições desnecessárias ao servidor.

Comment: Sim coluna obrigatorio (sim ou não). Eu usava required, mas mesmo assim prefiro utilizar por php mesmo!

Comment: @CarlosG esse código PHP bem no início é o que trata a requisição e que deverá fazer tal validação?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim, pensei em selecionar os campos obrigatórios do formulário com select antes do foreach e utilizar algo do tipo if(empty($result)){ será que dá?

Comment: @CarlosG Muitos erros exitem na sua lógica. Voce não pode simplesmente fazer o que quiser, pois existem boas práticas na programação e usabilidade.

Validar formulário através do servidor, depois de refresh, está longe de ser uma solução coerente, pois a utlização de javascript não apresenta nenhum tipo de risco para a sua aplicação e nem atrapalha o que voce está querendo fazer. 

Caso exista uma razão para você o tira-lo, fale logo, mas por enquanto posso responder que você desista do que está querendo fazer, por questões de usabilidade.

Comment: @CarlosG não precisa editar a resposta, colocando que resolveu o problema. Deixa a pergunta como está, com a resposta já dada, pra ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É muito importante, tanto em questão de usabilidade quanto em desempenho que você, no mínimo, coloque a propriedade `required` no seu HTML nos campos obrigatórios. Isso fará com que o usuário seja informado em tempo real, com uma mensagem no navegador, sobre quais campos ele deverá preencher e, também, evitará que seu servidor precise validar várias requisições desnecessárias. Também é válido ressaltar que mesmo fazendo isso no lado do cliente, a validação no servidor é obrigatória. **Nunca confie nos dados do seu cliente**.

Assim, aterei-me ao código referente à validação do formulário. Se entendi bem, a submissão do formulário gerará valores do tipo:

```
$_POST = [
    "acao" => "1",  // $row['id']
    "1" => ...,
    "2" => ...,
    "3" => ...,
];
```

Onde o campo `acao` é definido pelo valor de `$row['id']` e os outros são referentes aos campos cadastrados no banco de dados. Para saber quais são obrigatórios, você precisará buscar novamente os valores no banco:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $formulario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acao', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, nome FROM cms_formularios_campos WHERE formulario = '{$formulario}' and obrigatorio = 'sim' ORDER BY ID") or die(mysql_error());

    $erros = [];

    while($campo = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if (empty($_POST{$campo["id"]}))
        {
            // Algum campo obrigatório está em branco. Definir lógica do erro.
            $erros[] = "O campo {$campo['nome']} é obrigatório e não foi preenchido.";
        }
    }

    if (count($erros) === 0)
    {
        // Insere os valores da tabela de respostas
        // Utilize o input_filter ou filter_input_array para tratar os dados
    }
}
```

Após isso, seria possível você exibir as mensagens de erro no formulário fazendo:

```
foreach($erros as $erro)
{
    echo "<div class='erro'>{$erro}</div>";
}
```

Leitura importante: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Comment: Dei uma adaptada e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Começando pela lógica, você está criando um formulário dinamicamente, com os dados vindo do banco, legal, porém o campo 'obrigatório' na coluna dos formulários, não irá servir para nada, ao submeter o formulário para o servidor, podemos pegar a variável global gerada por seu `name`, e seu valor, não podemos identificar se o input era obrigatório ou não.

Então você tem 2 alternativas, fazer uma validação estática, ou uma gambiarra para poder utilizar o campo 'obrigatório' do banco, vou demonstrar a primeira alternativa.

**formulario.php**

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['empty'])){ ?>
  <strong id="empty">Erro! Favor preencher todos os campos!</strong>
<?php } ?>


<form action="valida.php" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="value1">

<input type="text" name="value2">

<input type="text" name="value3">

<input type="submit" value="enviar">

</form>
```

**valida.php**

```
<?php

//Caso value1 e value3 sejam obrigatórios.

if(empty($_POST['value1']) || empty($_POST['value3'])) {
     header( 'location: formulario.php?empty#empty' ); exit();
}

...

?>
```

Não testei mas é provável que funcione.

> Vou explicar por que a segunda alternativa é inviável.

Como disse anteriormente, não validar no cliente, trará inúmeras desvantagens, pois, ao submeter, você teria de buscar no banco os campos obrigatórios, trazendo algum atributo identificador para o mesmo, exemplo um id (creio que tenha esse campo pois no seu código ele aparece), esse id teria de estar de acordo com o name do formulário, para dai ser ser feita a verificação, com um looping para cada valor, sendo assim você...

- Perderá os dados do formulário.
- Perderá em manutenibilidade pois ficará preso a uma regra.
- Perderá em requisições ao servidor e em desempenho.

Comment: E que gambiarra seria esta?

Comment: Seria muito pedir por quê seria gambiarra utilizar a coluna `obrigatorio` do banco de dados?

Comment: Adicionei as informações necessárias.

Comment: Fazer a validação estática não fica mais preso ainda a uma regra? Você precisa definir manualmente os nomes dos campos e, visto que eles são dinâmicos, não tem como saber quais são.

Comment: De forma alguma @AndersonCarlosWoss, validação estática não é exemplo de dinamização, mas julgando que uma aplicação tenha mais de um formulário, a manutenção desses campos obrigatórios no banco seria horrível, a propósito, esse termo dinamização não caiu bem, vou trocar.